# What is the best companion for a solo PvE Trickster Rogue?

Tags: neverwinter

Should I go for a DPS, tank, or healing companion?

Any suggestions for the actual companion?  I heard the slyblade kobold is pretty good DPS companion, and that Galeb Duhr is the best tank companion (but he costs 30$ :/ )

I don't know much about the healing companions, and I didn't buy a Heroes or Guardian pack, so I don't have the Wolf or the Panther.  Has anyone had a good experience with a specific companion for the TR?

Comment: Doesn't having a companion defeat the purpose of "solo"?

Comment: @Yawus I suppose I'll bite...  Think of the companion in Neverwinter as the Hunter's Pet in WoW. Only in Neverwinter, every character class can have one.

Comment: @Yawus It's similar to the companion system in Star Wars: The Old Republic - they're NPC tag-alongs that get lesser versions of PC-styled powers to augment or aid you. They gain experience independently of your character and can advance in rank, equip various enhancements, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The dog companion is widely regarded as the best first-companion choice regardless of your class simply because it does the most damage.  The cleric (healer) companion heals so seldomly and for so little that it really isn't worth it unless you are playing a Guardian Fighter who is already fairly competent with the block so that the small heals she ends up casting are just topping you off since you are always fairly high.

The dog does a decent burst damage attack and has a knock down that he uses somewhat intelligently.

Of course, this is all based on the first 20 levels or so.  Once you max out the cleric companion for instance, she is healing pretty well as she has her HOT as well as her standard heal.  Naturally all of the starter options are going to be worthless once they hit companion level 15 (this will probably take a good 20-30 levels for you because its easy to forget to send them to train).  That is until they add the companion training books that allow you to raise their caps.

Answer (score 0):

The Healer is a good companion because his heal is quite good and saves you from using heal potions between the fights and saves you a lot of gold. But the Healer has a low survivability and will die in many boss fights.

A secondary companion may be useful. Especially the Dog, Panther or Wolf because they have abilities to knock down/disrupt enemies, have a higher survivability and do some damage. This makes them better for boss fights.

I do not suggest the Tank. He may tank some mob but overall he feeled quite useless. Galeb Duhr may do better but I never used him.

Some more information on the companions:
http://nw-forum.perfectworld.com/showthread.php?111111-Companion-info-and-a-bit-of-a-guide

Comment: The "Man at arms", is absolutely not useless! Especially for the new Hunter/Ranger class it's the most valued early companion next to the Cleric. Not sure about Dog, but most early HR were using either Man at arms or Cleric.
On my HR I use Man at arms almost continuously, because he's actually great in grabbing the attention of your target. You just need to get the hang of it.
One way is, attack the tough enemy first so the Man at arms charges to it and grabs agro. Then you can kill the adds while it's busy.
Situational or whenever the Man at arms is on training I would use the Cleric.

Answer (score 0):

I've played the first 40 levels so far as a "mostly stealth" orientated TS build (items and build concentrate on recovery, power, and defence - to stay in, or get back to, stealth as much as possible).

DPS pets are only really viable in a group (having only tried the sellsword and dog my opinion is limited), the devoted cleric is great "in general" play but once a boss hits her a few times (or she gets gang 'ticked' by minions) = she's dead.

I find a tank pet is great for getting combat advantage - especially if you give them some 'regen/life steal/def' magics and items. Galeb Duhr has a disadvantage of only being mindful of one target.. BUT if it is the right target that's great.  Sometimes it isn't, so it can take you a while to get back on track with some fancy footwork, judicious rolling, stealth and Bait & Switch to distract the enemy while you go rub some life into his earthen limbs.

I play a Halfling, so always impressed with anything that is competent and shorter than me. Unfortunately, the dog and cleric die far too often when I use stealth (which is most of the time).  If you play a different build you may have different experiences. :)

Answer (score 0):

On my Trickster/Rogue I mainly use the Cleric. It's supposedly the best early companion for TR, since the Rogue does awesome damage on its own and a free healer is always good.
You're not however limited to just one companion; it's even advised to fill up all 3 free slots, because of the specific companion bonuses which all get added to you, even when they're not active.

Comment: Having all the active companions you can is, of course, important. I also thing the apprentice healer is useful as the summoned companion. The early level 15 limitation is unfortunate, but you can upgrade to green, blue, and purple levels for cheaper than buying an all new companion. Then again, more companions helps in Sword Coast Adventures, and it's still real money equivalent to upgrade -- you won't have the AD from PvE before hitting the first cap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some straight up advice, do not buy the Pheora. I spent 30$ on that hot headed bird and all it does is get me into unnecessary combat.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

the best companions in the game are the stones that fly around your head... you get all their stats... and become a one man wrecking crew. Start early, level it like crazy... you'll never look back. BEST COMPANION IN THE GAME - stone of allure or whatever. They make clark kent into superman.

Comment: This is also what I see on the forums, but I'm not convinced the stones are good for general solo PvE. If you give them all regen, they still wouldn't provide the same level of heal and utility and the apprentice healer.

Comment: This is a little less true in Module 6, but still a very good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Having leveled many character to 11th level for leadership, the white control wizard is by far the best basic pet for the low levels. It as an AoE that will wipe out enemy parties with a single blow at least until the Tower District, and does plenty of damage there too.

At higher levels, basic (white) companions are pretty useless.  The best choice of companion depends on what you need more of (power, crit, etc) and on your playstyle.

The easy and usually not-wrong choice as an active companion is any type of ioun stone, as they directly provide you with stat benefits and do not attack monsters on their own.  The cat is also a good choice for similar reasons, though I have seen it fall through the floor and get stuck once.

The [Air Archon](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Air_Archon) is a good choice as an inactive companion for any DPS class, as it gives you a 5% damage bonus (at blue level) to anything not at full health.

Here is [the full list](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Companion#List_of_Companions).